# Naming array dimensions in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working with threedimensional arrays and it would be neat if I could name the array dimensions. The question marks in the example below are giving me the idea that this is possible.

Is it, and if so, how does it work? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

[image: Example]

Comment: The questions marks are asking you to specify the _count_ of the dimensions.

Comment: Your question isn't clear -- what would it mean to "name" the dimensions? You could probably do something with a custom datatype with three fields.

Comment: Haha should have known that, I guess I have to change my `(24,5,8)` to `(0 To 25, 0 To 5, 0 To 8)` in my dim in that case.

Comment: With naming I mean like when you for example call a sub you see which variables are required

Comment: Being explicit about the lower bounds doesn't make the question marks go away

Comment: No you can't, What you are asking for is meta attributes and VBA does not support them.

Answer (score 4):

The three question marks are showing you that this array has three dimensions. If there was only one question mark, it would mean that the variable was declared as one dimensional. This is built in to VB and can't be change, as far as I know.

I think there's real value into making your code more readable and self-documenting. If I had a three dim array, I would probably create some custom class modules to model the objects that I was using.

If your first dimension is a SchoolID, your second dimension is a ClassID, and your third dimension is a StudentID, then code using custom class modules like this

```
Debug.Print Schools(10).Classes(3).Students(7).Name
```

is more readable than

```
Debug.Print arrLeeftijdenG5(10,3,7)
```

I don't know what you're storing, so it's just an example. Consider using custom class module to model the real-world objects your code is manipulating. There's a bit more set up involved, but it pays dividends down the road.