# VBA - How to refer to column names in Array?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

To start, I have a scraping function that scrapes a table from a web page, and stores the data in a 2D array.

The 2D array starts from row 0 to however many rows of data are on the page, and columns 1 to however many columns there are.

Row 0 simply contains all the column names.

My ReDim:

```
ReDim Addresses(0 To lngTotalRecords, 1 To columns.Count) As String
```

I've then stored this 2D array into a scripting dictionary called dictClients, as there are multiple clients that all have their own entries for the same table on the web page.

So in my dictionary I have something like the following to refer to a particular address table for a particular client:

```
dictClients(1)("Addresses")
dictClients(2)("Addresses")
```

I now want to be able to check if a cell in a certain row contains a specific value, however the web page allows the columns to be reorganized so that:

```
dictClients(1)("Addresses")(1,1) 'row 1 column 1
```

will not always refer to the "Street Number" column. The street number column could be the following for someone else for example:

```
dictClients(1)("Addresses")(1,3) ' row 1 column 3
```

Given that these cells:

```
dictClients(1)("Addresses")(0,1) '(0,2) (0,3) etc.
```

all refer to the column's names, what's the best way for me to find the position of a particular named column?

Example: I want to get the value of the Postal Code cell in row 1, so I need to look in 
`dictClients(1)("Addresses")(1, POSTALCODECOLUMN)`, 
which isn't always in the same position on the web page.

I was thinking of using the following function:

```
Public Function column(strArr() As String, strColumnName As String)
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To UBound(strArr, 2)
If strArr(0, i) = strColumnName Then column = i
Next
End Function
```

But it just feels so lengthy calling it like:

```
strPostalCode = 
dictClients(1)("Addresses")(1,column(dictClients(1)("Addresses"), "Postal Code")
```

Is there a better and easier way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's strange how all the scraping questions come in at once. My standard answer: ***Welcome to Stack Overlow!* "How to scrape web pages?" is one of the most common Excel/VBA questions on this site (close to 1000 questions & answers) and elsewhere. I find it hard to believe that you've exhausted all [options](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrape+excel) before posting. Please see the [help/on-topic] and also "[ask]" and [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/) and also: [mcve]. If you run into a problem not covered elsewhere, [edit] your post.*Good Luck*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping data from website using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27066963/scraping-data-from-website-using-vba)

Comment: @ashleedawg looks to me like web scraping is incidental to the Q.  Real Q is about accessing an array with named columns

Comment: @loael your function look ok to me as is.  But if you really want to improve it, look into using a Class.  You could then create a Method that accepts a row number and column name, returns the required data.  Its call might look like `strPostalCode = Clients.GetData(1, "Addresses")`

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

The simplest answer may be to use `ListObjects`:

```
ListObject("Table1").ListColumns("Column1").DataBodyRange...
```

### Option 2

Referencing [Dick Kusleika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4280/dick-kusleika)'s answer in [Naming array dims in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681406/naming-array-dimensions-in-excel-vba#:%7E:text=If%20I%20had%20a%20three%20dim%20array%2C%20I%20would%20probably%20create%20some%20custom%20class%20modules%20to%20model%20the%20objects%20that%20I%20was%20using.):

> If I had a three dim array, I would probably ***create some custom class modules*** to model the objects that I was using.
>
> If your first dimension is a SchoolID, your second dimension is a ClassID, and your third dimension is a StudentID, then code using custom class modules like this

```
Debug.Print Schools(10).Classes(3).Students(7).Name
```

> is more readable than

```
Debug.Print arrLeeftijdenG5(10,3,7)
```